# Blog URL Structure - Multiple Taxonomies

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

Does anyone know how, if it's possible, to include a base slug, two taxonomies and the blog title are the URL?

All posts would have either one or two categories.

e.g.
/blog/{category-one}/{category-two}/{blog-title}

Answer (score 1):

Update any custom post types so they use 'with_front' => FALSE in the slug parameters and update your permalink setting to /blog/%category%/%postname%/.

Create your categories with sub categories.